# Just got a 2020 BAODIAO BD125-11GT motorcycle wont start

Tags: no-crank-no-start

When I picked it up, guy started it right up no problem. When I got home, I couldn't get to start. All lights and things came on but no sound or turnover. Then friend hooked to battery pack and now no lights or anything working. He tried with screw driver to turn over and it sounded like it wanted to start. But with no power it wouldn't. Now I don't no what to do from here. Not sure what he did to make lights and all not work but I'm super confused and not sure what to do. Thanks

Comment: Are you supposed to pull the clutch or brake to enable starting? Did you friend break something? If the lights were working why the battery pack?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Step 1) phone the person who sold it to you. Step 2) take it to a reputable bike shop.

Comment: No don't have to pull clutch or break. I tested with voltage meter and getting power If I'm battery all the way to the cylinoid. Checked the fuses They are good, so I'm wondering if it'starters silinoid. Does anyone know if there's any more than the 2 fuses by the starter Illinois? Which one is working and when is the backup? Is there any that would be up closer to the starter switch?